# Can Python create a self contained package that can be deployed where python and pip is not installed?

Tags: python

Some programming languages provide capability t create a self contained packages that can run on any machine.

For example, dotnet core can self-contained apps per below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained

The C# self-contained apps can be single large file, or a directory of all files required to run the application. The package can target Linux, mac or Windows.

In Python, what is the closest feature to self-contained app packages described above?

Comment: One way or another you require an interpreter. What projects like PyInstaller do is bundle the interpreter/runtime and requirements all together. That's what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) seems to be the current go to, and it works well in my experience. However, some people have reported that it has very large file sizes, but I've personally never found that to be a major issue.

If you use that, you would also probably need some kind of UI, but that's a separate issue in itself.